# Can you set a JavaScript breakpoint in a UserControl?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio 2008, [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET). Can you set a [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) breakpoint in a UserControl ascx page?  I can set it in an aspx page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you uncheck **Disable Script Debugging** in Internet Explorer it should hit **debugger** lines and prompt you with either the Built-In Debugger or you can use VS IDE. I don't think you need a semicolon afterwards

```
var i = 0;
debugger
// do work
```

Comment: If you're using the Firebug plugin for FireFox you can put a breakpoint on a certain line as well, similar to putting a breakpoint on a .net line of code

Comment: It should be noted that the answer to the question is no, you cannot set a JavaScript breakpoint in a UserControl (ascx) file in the same manor as you can in an aspx page.  This holds true for even VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Should not be any difference, a UserControl is just a part of an aspx page.

Writing `debugger;` in your script where you want a to start debugging usually solves it for me, and then choose either VS 2008 or any other debugger you may prefer in the select debugger window that appears.
Or, if you use Firefox, just make sure you have Firebug active when you reach that point in the code.